# Why can "select * from table* cause a transaction to be non-serializable (postgres)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i run two transactions with isolation level serializable in parallel. these contain the same statements:
select * from table;
insert into table values ... ;

(i took the exact case from this video https://youtu.be/4EajrPgJAk0?t=1472 at 24:34)
i can reproduce the same error as in the video, but removing the select statement makes the inserts pass. if i remove the inserts, the selects pass.

now my question(s):

- why does the select cause the transactions to fail? it's just a select, it performs no insert or update. the updates alone do not fail. logically, this makes no sense to me.
- according to an assignment i saw, it's apparently possible to reproduce an error in mode serializable, make the transactions pass with "read committed", and all that with a single statement per transactions.
  my understanding after watching the video above doesn't allow this. waht obvious thing am i misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

As described in detail in the documentation[1], postgres will determine if data modified by one transaction is accessed by the other.  In the case you remove the selects that will not be the case, presumably.

[1] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE

Comment: i see. so the sql server is paranoid and assumes everything that was read may be relevant for any insert or update

Comment: It's smarter than paranoia.  See the section on predicate locking.

Comment: In particular, it depends on the execution plan used to calculate the result. If that was a sequential scan, all the rows are SI locked.

Comment: @HamsterofDeath  That isn't paranoia, that is merely a correct implementation of serializable, in the absence of the ability to read minds.  If the data you selected is not relevant to the INSERT, they shouldn't be done in the same transaction.